# By restarting system terminal does not recognize npm and node commands

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, macos-mojave, nvm

I have installed node and npm by nvm; At the end of instaling nvm, below message was shown:

```
Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

So I run that command and use nvm, install node versions and npm.

But when I restart my system, I have to run above command otherwise terminal says command not found.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nvm installation should have added a couple of lines to your shell initialization script that makes sure to initialize nvm in every new shell, but for some reason this seems to have not happened.

Assuming that you're using bash, try adding these lines to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"
```

Then start a new terminal session and see if that does the trick.

Another thing that could be worth double-checking is to see if you have any installed node version aliased as the default one. I'm not sure what nvm does if you don't have a default version specified (if that's even possible). Run `nvm ls` and see you you have `default` pointing to any installed version of Node. If not, then set that up by running `nvm alias default [version-number]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; your solution fix npm and node command; but nvm command shows `command not found: nvm`. As I understand that bash lines must fix nvm problem too but it does not, do you have any idea about it